# Intercepting file access

Tags: file, interception

I have a program (a game, really), which uses a `.wad` file to store its resources. Is it possible to somehow intercept access to this file, and emulate it?

For instance, I want to dynamically replace some sprites. Instead of creating a new file, is it possible to make this game think it is accessing the `.wad`, but actually we process its requests?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109564/intercept-windows-open-file

Answer (score 4):

Under Windows the [File System Filter Driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641617) provides a low level I/O hook that a program can register to be passed the I/O requests to the file system.

Filter drivers can also alter the data passed via filters or deny filesystem requests.

Implementation, maintenance and support of your such kernel-mode code is **non-trivial**.

Anyway you could also take a look at:

- [Winpooch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winpooch/): an antivirus has to intercept file accesses so an open source antivirus can be a good starting point to study filters.
- [EasyHook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking#_2_3): for Windows API hooking