# How to intercept exe files launch from windows explorer?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

i want to be notified when when user trys to open a file from the explorer.

How could this be done?
I tired hooking some winapi in the explorer.exe with no hope.

I also want to intercept this call and cancel it.

Comment: Things that sound like malware....

Comment: not a malware im trying to protect myself actually from one

Comment: Why do you want to detect explorer creating a process? Any process can create a process?

Comment: Vote to reopen. "Launch from Explorer" is a Shell operation, and the supposed duplicate is far broader (covers all launches). Obviously, in this case an answer which stops _all_ programs from executing breaks the OS.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at a similar question: [Intercept windows open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109564/intercept-windows-open-file)

Also for the people asking why someone would want to do this or immediately jump to malware conclusions. There are a number of legitimate uses for this. Especially if you are creating a B2B product that deals with automation or control over a customer's PC environment.