# how to get notified when a process wants to open a file?

Tags: windows, winapi, notifications, createfile, fanotify

I want to write a program that will be notified and do a certain event each time a process wants to open a file, and will we able to allow the process access to a new file or disallow it.
For example: I want it to work like the **fanotify** API in linux.
Is there any way to do the same thing under windows ?

I want it to notify me when the OpenFile or CreateFile or other functions that work with files run:
[CreateFile Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dknl8.png)

Comment: write minifilter driver

Comment: Or buy a third-party file system filter driver, or use API hooking.  Depends on your circumstances, really.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept windows open file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109564/intercept-windows-open-file)